# Sinks and baths have faucets (that are) attached to them

Tags: relative-clauses, sentence-usage, reduced-relative-clauses

> A faucet is a device that controls the flow of a liquid or gas from a
> pipe or container. Sinks and baths have faucets attached to them.

This is the definition of the word **faucet**. My question is, if we replace the last sentence with "*Sinks and baths have faucets **that are** attached to them*", is it going to sound less natural or even a bit clumsy compared to the original one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "which are" omitted from this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18712/is-which-are-omitted-from-this-sentence) In your context, ***attached to them*** looks to me like a *reduced relative clause — a relative clause from which the relative expression and linking verb [**which/that are**] have been deleted.* As covered by earlier question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Sinks and baths have faucets attached to them.

> Sinks and baths have faucets that are attached to them.

Both are fine, but the original (without "that are") reads better.

(*Note:* Although common in North America, the word "faucet" is never used in British English: the term "tap" is used instead.)